# What is tpl and how do I interprete it in extJS context?

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
Ext.define('App.view.util.NavigationView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    tpl: [''
        ,'<ul class="app-navigation-container">'
        , '<tpl for=".">'
        , '<a href="#{navigationToken}">'
        ,'<li class="app-navigation-pane {iconCls}">'
        , '<h2>{title}</h2>'
        , '<p>{description}</p>'
        , '</li>'
        , '</a>'
        , '</tpl>'
        , '</ul>'
        , '<div class="x-clear"></div>'
    ]
});
```

I am new to ExtJS and I am debugging some small client-side issues which involved ExtJS. How can I update the 
navigationToken variable in other files. I have some listeners like 'select' listener in which I would like to change the value for navigationToken.

Comment: [this example](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/platform/templates.html) should help clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component has a property called '[data](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-data)', which is part of the extended panel. This property is used to provide the [template](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) as defined in '[tpl](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-tpl)' with data, which can set as a property.

So in your listener you can set the data property by calling

```
var data = [{
    navigationToken: 'navigationToken1',
    iconCls: 'iconCls',
    title: 'title1',
    description: 'description1'
}, {
    navigationToken: 'navigationToken1',
    iconCls: 'iconCls',
    title: 'title2',
    description: 'description2'
}];

[view].update(data);
```

where [view] should references to your 'App.view.util.NavigationView'.

Comment: Great! Keep in mind that a template on a panel like this is maybe not what you want, if you want to update data of it.

A better approach for dynamic lists would be a dataview or a tree. You could then have a model and a store, which is bind to the dataview or tree. If you then update records (links in your case) in that store, the view is updated automatically with the data from the store.

Comment: That is precisely what is done in the code, I have written a navigationTree and binded that to the tpl dynamically changing data.